# Using the parameter error to separate failed process's in async.mapLimit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using async.mapLimit to make some concurrency procedures upon an array with limit of 10:

```
async.mapLimit(files, 10, function(file, callback) {

   ... etc...

}, function(error, files) {

   ... etc..
});
```

Inside the main function, i'm executing a async operation with child_process, and if everything happen as it should, i just call the callback:

```
callback(null, files);
```

But... when something bad happens, i also NEED call the callback passing the file, because i don't want end everything, i just assign the file with a error property and call the callback:

```
file.error = error;
callback(null, file);
```

So, when the second async.mapLimit callback is fired, i have an array of files:

```
, function(error, files) {

   console.log(files); 
});
```

output:

```
[
   {
    name: 'file_2',
    error: 'something'...
   },
   {
    name: 'file_1',
    ...etc
   }
]
```

So, i need separate the files that failed, doing:

```
var failedFiles = [];
var okFiles = [];

files.forEach(function(file) {
   if (file.error)
     failedFiles.push(file);
   else
     okFiles.push(file;
});
```

I would like to know if isn't possible to return the files that failed as an array, and access then by the parameter error of the second async.mapLimit callback.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async.mapLimit()` will stop immediately when an iteration "returns" an error, so it's not possible to do what you want.

As an alternative, instead of using `async.mapLimit()` you could use `async.eachLimit()` and push the file objects into the respective array inside the iterator function:

```
var failedFiles = [];
var okFiles     = [];

async.eachLimit(files, 10, function(file, callback) {
  if (SOME_ERROR) {
    failedFiles.push(file);
  } else {
    okFiles.push(file);
  }
  callback();
}, function(err) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I was using this with map-limit and i was with that feeling "something is not right".. hahaha